# Platform Independence: How is it different from moving source code from one OS to another?

Tags: c#, java, php, c++, c

What is the exact definition of platform independent. I have read Java is a platform independent language, because it converts the source code into byte code And that byte-code can be run on any OS which has Java virtual machine Installed.

I am confused about, If I have some source code from any other language say C, PHP, VB, C#, C++, RubyOnRails etc, and this source-code can be run on any OS which has the corresponding compiler/interpreter on it. So why don't we say C or other languages are also a platform independent languages.

*Java is actually very much dependent on the Java platform. Also, C is arguably a very portable language. – Niklas*

Comment: Java is actually very much dependent on the Java platform. Also, C is arguably a very portable language.

Comment: Refrain from link bombing in future

Comment: Portability and platfom independency are two different concepts though.

Answer (score 4):

Programming languages intended to interact directly with the operating system (such as C) tend to be seen as platform *dependent*, simply because one system may provide one set of system-calls, and another system another set of system-calls. The application may thus be *dependent* on what platform it executes on.

Surely a compiled Java-program depends on the platform in the sense that it depends on the presence of a JVM. As opposed to a compiled C-program however, it independent of the underlying operating system and follow the [*compile once, run anywhere*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere) principle.

Here's a quote from [this webpage](http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Platform-independent_programming)

> *Platform Independent Programming is achieved when a program works on several platforms. Platform Independent applications shall work the same way on any Operating System, for any Processor Architecture and so on. Java is a well known language for creating such applications.*

---

Formally speaking (and I like to speak formally) any program written in a language with a *well defined semantics* (which covers 99% of all languages) can of course be executed on any platform.

**Related question:**

- [Is Java cross platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978005/is-java-cross-platform)
- [Is .NET platform independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656721/is-net-platform-independent)
- [Why is Java Platform Independent](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_java_is_platform_independent)

Answer (score 2):

This ideally means write once with no worries about specific platform things, compile once and run everywhere. But this is really difficult to achieve.