# Visual Studio Express Editions - Windows specific

Tags: c#, .net

I am a beginner to .NET and C# and I started out with the book 'Pro C# 6.0 and .NET 4.6 Framework'.

Quote from the book:

> Each of the Express tools is limited in that it allows you to build
>   .NET software that will run only on the Windows OS (7, 8.x, or 10).
>   However, as mentioned in Chapter 1, the .NET platform runs on a wide
>   variety of operating systems and hardware devices. Thus, if you need
>   to build a .NET program that can run on (for example) Android or an
>   Apple product, the Express products won’t offer much help.

I have difficulty in understanding what this means. From my understanding .NET assemblies (managed code) will be platform-independent. So why should the code generated by Express verions of the IDE be specific to Windows only? Shouldn't the CIL generated be equally eligible to run on mono framework (assuming am not using any of the frameworks not supported by mono like WPF and so on) in Linux or Mac OS X? Can someone please clarify what this means? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a product from Microsoft, the Express edition has its own goal of serving only the Windows developers. Whether that program will also be supported by Mono goes beyond the scope of the product, whether you want it or not. That's what the author means. If you do want to learn Mono or Xamarin, you definitely should go to other books, or apply the knowledge on your own.

Comment: The book is wrong, Express is not limited to managed .NET development. There are versions for native development, too. The issue with Express, though, isn't a technical one, but rather a marketing one. It is important to keep those two concepts distinct in your mind. Microsoft artificially limits some of its software, including Visual Studio, to segment the market. Also keep distinct the concept of the IDE that you use to develop software, versus the software itself. The author admittedly does a poor job here, too.

Comment: Managed code is platform independent but the libraries you use are not.  A WPF app will never run on an Android or Apple machine, it is married too heavily to DirectX.  The only kind of user interface that can be platform agnostic is a console mode app or a web page.  You'll never sell one in the Android or Apple store, users expect an app that uses the native toolkit widgets.  Xamarin makes a business out of it, the book author would not yet know that the company was bought by Microsoft btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of Visual Studio (and the community edition):

> includes Windows SDK's compilers and core files, which developers can
>   use to build Win32 applications

If you build a C# *web* application then that application will still be accessible to *other platforms* users if the application is hosted on a Windows server (or a Mac/Linux server using Mono instead of .Net).

> With web applications you only need to ensure your html/jscript etc.
>   is compatible with the users browser, although the server OS and web
>   server matter in terms of hosting the web app.

In that case, the client *does not* run your C# .NET application, *you do* (the Windows server).

But if you are building a *normal* C# .NET application (not a web app) for an OS, then you can only develop for Windows, as you don't have the compiler for anything else.

---

Side note about platform independence: You can see an interesting debate on [this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656721/is-net-platform-independent) about it. The question is 5 years old, but the answer is new (2016).

Comment: I have accepted this answer for the link provided to another stackoverflow post. The answer there did indeed answer my question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

> I have difficulty in understanding what this means. From my understanding .NET assemblies (managed code) will be platform-independent.

Yes Express verions of the IDE be specific to Windows only. and other platform go with Visual studio Code

> Shouldn't the CIL generated be equally eligible to run on mono framework

Yes it should but it has to rebuild in the mono framework

Comment: I don't understand. If I write managed code that is CLSCompliant should I still need to rebuild it against Mono framefork for me to run it there? If that is the case then how is C# different from other languages like C++? I thought C# was also a WORA (Write once - Run anywhere) language like Java.

Comment: You can develop the application Mono framwork in windows also it will run anyware , Read here get more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656721/is-net-platform-independent